# ILNumerics.Misc.ILThreadPool' threw an exception when ILNumerics.Settings.UseThreadAffinity is not manually set to false

Tags: c#, threadpool, ilnumerics

Sometimes when I use ILMath functions such as `ILMath.linspace` and others, the following exception is thrown without obvious reason.

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'ILNumerics.Misc.ILThreadPool' threw an exception.
  Source=ILNumerics
  TypeName=ILNumerics.Misc.ILThreadPool
  StackTrace:
       at ILNumerics.Misc.ILThreadPool.Wait4Workers(Int32& workerCount)
       at ILNumerics.ILMath.multiplyElem(ILInArray`1 A, ILInArray`1 B)
       at ILNumerics.ILDenseArray`1.op_Multiply(ILDenseArray`1 A, ILDenseArray`1 B)
       at ILNumerics.ILMath.linspace[T](ILBaseArray start, ILBaseArray end, ILBaseArray length)
       at ILNumerics.ILMath.linspace(ILBaseArray start, ILBaseArray end, ILBaseArray length)
       at *** in ***\Numerics\NumericsTest.cs:line 104
       at *** in ***\Numerics\NumericsTest.cs:line 94
  InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=The parameter is incorrect
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       NativeErrorCode=87
       StackTrace:
            at System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread.set_ProcessorAffinity(IntPtr value)
            at ILNumerics.Misc.ILThreadPool..ctor(Int32 maxThreads)
            at ILNumerics.Misc.ILThreadPool..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

By trial and error, I realized that if I set `ILNumerics.Settings.UseThreadAffinity = false`,
The code then executes without error. I read from ILNumerics documentation that `UseThreadAffinity` should default to false, which in my case it is definitely set to true by default. Is this a bug? Another problem I notice that the documentation also mentions I can use App.config to change default settings, I tried that and the `ILNIsHosted` actually does what it says, but `ILNUseThreadAffinity` has no effect at all on the `UseThreadAffinity` setting. It is still “true” even though I tried set it to false. Is this a bug of ILNumerics? I’m using ILNumerics 3.2.2.0 (any CPU)obtained from NuGet directly. The code is running in VS2010 on Windows 7 64bit.

```
   <appSettings>
    <add key="ILNIsHosted" value="true" />
    <add key="ILNUseThreadAffinity" value="false"/>
   </appSettings>
```

---

To add on to the original question, I went to download the source code of ILNumerics community edition and discovered something strange.

ILSettings.cs contains the following:

```
public static bool UseThreadAffinity {
    get { return s_isHosted; }
    set { s_isHosted = value; }
}
```

These lines don't make sense to me. Why is UseThreadAffinity set to s_isHosted. I think this may be why when I set ILNIsHosted to true, the thread affinity changed to true as well.

Comment: You name it. It is a bug!

Comment: It is issue #166 in the ILNumerics bugtracker now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment to my question previously. I recently found that ILMemoryPoolInternal throws StackOverflowException sometimes when running under isHosted mode in Windows Presentation Foundation. I couldn't figure out a definite way to reproduce it. It just randomly pops up when I use ILMath.multiply(m1.T, m2), where m1 and m2 are just column vectors. When I change this line to a simple sum of m1 * m2, the error never shows up. The error shows up equally frequently when I use ILNumerics 3.2.1.0 or 3.2.2.0 AnyCPU versions.

Comment: Qian, please file a bug report for this issue in the bugtracker: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis Thanks!

Comment: the first issue will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: A bug report is filed here [link[(https://mediaautomat.de/mantis/view.php?id=171) The ILMemoryPool error seems unrelated to ILThreadPool. Version 3.2.1.0 shows no ILThreadPool error but has the same ILMemoryPool error. 3.2.2.0 has both errors.